# Linear Algebra quick question over isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

can someone provide me an example of two isomorphic subspaces of r2 that are not identical? I am just curious since I can only find ones that are identical

Comment: Any two distinct lines through the origin in $\Bbb R^2$ are isomorphic vector spaces but are distinct (read: not identical) subspaces. Geometrically, this should have been obvious. Did you not know what the word "identical" meant? It's literally not even possible to "only find ones that are identical" - if you pick any two subspaces that aren't the same then by definition they are not identical.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that by "r2" you mean $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ I suggest you to take for instance $\mathbb{R}\left(1,0\right)$ and $\mathbb{R}\left(0,1\right)$.